# React redux shared object between components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

I'm coming from Angular over to React and therefore are scratching my head, trying to figure out how to share an object between two components.

I'm running into trouble when I update my object, as the new values aren't updated across components. As I'm not allowed to reference the same object (due to immutability in Redux) I'm having a hard time to figure out how to do this the best.

What's the correct, most simple and best way of achieving what I want? Here's an illustration:

[image]

*(this illustration does not represent my app but has been simplified to make it easier to understand what I want to achieve. My React components are nested in multiple layers, which is why I thought Redux would be the solution)*

... and here's how I've structured my redux object so far:

```
export default function reducer(state = {
  blocks: [{ title: '', description: '' }],
  currentBlock: null,
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'UPDATE_BLOCK_TITLE':
      return {...state,
        blocks: state.blocks.map((block, i) => block === action.payload.block ? {...block, title: action.payload.title} : block)
      }

    case 'SET_CURRENT_BLOCK':
      return {...state, currentBlock: action.payload }

  }
  return state;
}
```

My `UPDATE_BLOCK_TITLE` case makes sure to update a field in the object, whilst my `SET_CURRENT_BLOCK` updates which block to be shown on the right-hand side.

I find it a little cumbersome if I have to update both the title and the currentBlock every time I change the title, especially coming from Angular where this sort of thing would be very easy to achieve.

Maybe I'm looking at implementing it the wrong way? Please let me know what the best way of achieving this is.

Comment: Instead of storing the whole object, store the index as currentBlock, then you wont have to change two objects.

Comment: You raise two issues in your question - 1) that state is not being shared between the two components; 2) how state is shared feels cumbersome to you. Others have provided some guidance on #2, what about #1? Are you able to see shared state across your components?

Comment: @ChadMoore Thanks for providing your help. In regards to #1 I'm seeing changes when storing a reference ID in currentBlock instead. Thanks!

Comment: Jordan gave a great answer but I wanted to share an updated link to the official Redux article on [Structuring Reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/structuring-reducers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Redux way is to keep your data normalized.

According to your use-case, you should keep only the `block.id` (or any other block identifier) in `currentBlock`. Doing it that way - when you modify the `blocks` store itself, all related components will receive the updated block, because they will rely on the relation `block.id`.

[How do I organize nested or duplicate data in my state?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#how-do-i-organize-nested-or-duplicate-data-in-my-state)

> Data with IDs, nesting, or relationships should generally be stored in a “normalized” fashion: each object should be stored once, keyed by ID, and other objects that reference it should only store the ID rather than a copy of the entire object. It may help to think of parts of your store as a database, with individual “tables” per item type. Libraries such as normalizr and redux-orm can provide help and abstractions in managing normalized data.

I would suggest you to walk through the official Redux documentation about [Structuring Reducers](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers). It's very well written and structured, so you will learn the main concepts and best practices from Redux creators.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I didn't have a ID in the object stored inside my "blocks"-array but I've implemented an ID now. I didn't store an ID to begin with as I was wasn't sure how to update it once I my application is hooked up to a backend that will provide this. Right now I'm creating a temporary ID and will have to figure out what to do when my backend is ready. I'll read up on structuring reducers and probably learn a lot. Thanks a lot!